# node : open cmd.exe command prompt in windows mode without launching a command

Tags: node.js, cmd

From node , I want to open a basic command prompt window commonly located in %windir%\system32\cmd.exe

I don't want to launch a special command, I just want to open the window as I had clicked on the Command prompt link.

I tried to do this command in express:

```
const cmdPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
let commande = `${cmdPath}`;
    var exec = require("child_process").exec;
    exec(commande, function callback(error, stdout, stderr) {
      res.end();
    });
res.end();
```

It does not seems to work , I don't see a window opening.

Would you have any idea please?

Comment: "It does not seems to work"

what exactly doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I don't see a window opening.

Comment: Add /k to your command line.  See if that helps.

Comment: That for tip but  unfortunately it changes nothing